# get last arraylist position before streak gets interrupted

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, android-recyclerview

https://www.google.com/search?q=message+image+on+last&sxsrf=ALeKk01qNrLQ61yRXCMSPRxyNaoI0MF_kA:1605295893515&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj2veboYDtAhWeIbcAHebnB4QQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1366&bih=657#imgrc=wzgnznL_g7kUsM

I want to show profile image like shown in above link only at last message of every consecutive messages from same person. Please help me with this.

I have tried many ways but I don't know to hide visibility of top images

```
if (position > 0) { 
if (messageList.get(i).getFrom.equalsIgnoreCase(messagesList.get(position - 1).getFrom())) 
{ 
    viewHolder.mProfileImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
} 
else 
{ 
    viewHolder.mProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
} 
} 
else 
{ 
viewHolder.mProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
}
```

I have used above code and get this result which is shown in this https://i.stack.imgur.com/92SUb.jpg link. With this code I am able to hide all the images other than the first one image. can you please show me the way to hide top message image and not the last one of streak.

Comment: Please add code of your bindViewHolder function or complete adapter class

Comment: Bindviewholder contains mainly this code to achieve the above output

Comment: I am using above code to hide images from position where getfrom equals getfrom-1 means i only left with first position where getfrom equals getfrom and then break and then again same code runs again

Comment: What I get from your question is

You need to show profileImage only when it is the last message in the streak.
But You are specifically on your code showing profileImage on first element of the list.
I don't know your message list contains all messages or only the message streak.

Comment: if (position > 0) { } else {viewHolder.mProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }

else part here means you want to show the profile image on the first message of the list.

Comment: Any other answers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to assume few things in my answer.
i.e.

1. messageList is the list of all messages. not the list of only consecutive/streak messages.
2. you need to show profile images for both sender and receiver.
3. And you want to only show the profileImage of last consecutive message.

So, here what you should do.

```
int length = messageList.lenght; //getTotalLenght;
String fromCurrent = messageList[position].getFrom(); //getFrom of current message being painted or shown
String fromNext = fromCurrent; //next message is set to current by default, to avoid error
if(length > postition+1) {
    fromNext = messageList[position+1].getFrom(); //if there is next message then get its sender but if it is the last message then nextSender and currentSender are same as I set its default value to the currentSender.
}
console.log("TAG", "FromNext: " + fromNext);
console.log("TAG", "FromCurrent: " + fromCurrent);
if(!fromCurrent.equals(fromNext)) { //checking if last message or not
    viewHolder.mProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
}
else {
    viewHolder.mProfileImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
}
```

Comment: yes messageList contains all messages and you understand my question correctly but from your code the problem is that it only hides image from last position of messageList not from the consecutive message please see the output on this link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1BPD.jpg in this link i also want to hide image which is with message 112.

Comment: My code only shows the image of the last position of consecutive message and hides all other images.

Comment: Do you only want to show the first image of the consecutive message?

Comment: with my code i got the first image of the consecutive message but your code not showing image of the last position of consecutive message but it only shows image on last position of messageList

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/h1BPD.jpg like you can see in this image your code only hides image on last position of adapter not with other last position of consecutive message like i also want to hide image with message 112

Comment: okay what is difference between `i` and `position` in your code? it might be the problem/cofusion with `i` and `position`.

Comment: Add the code to your adapter and viewHolder, It will help a lot to better my answer. Although the algorithm in my code is correct, read comment, I might have done some error in syntax or missplaced i with position.

Comment: i and position same its viewholder position

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlqoM.jpg as requested this is the code i am using please check

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/224924/private?tab=general
lets have a chat here

Comment: sorry man but stackoverflow shows i need atleast 20 reputation to chat privately so i can't talk to you on chat

Comment: any other answers ?

Comment: your code needs debugging. I need to know why fromNext and fromCurrent are always not equal. they should be not equal only when it is the last message of the streak.

Comment: I have added `console.log` in the code, if you can run it and put the logs here and send a screen shot. I can find the problem.

Comment: man you are amazing i got what i need. i think you slightly change your above code with this if(!fromCurrent.equals(fromNext)). i got the results but just one problem that it is not showing image with last position of messageList please check this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hd0r.jpg

Comment: `String fromNext = fromCurrent;` change it to `String fromNext = null;`

Comment: Ah I changed it, because I thought != was comparing the address not the value. So, I changed it to .equal().